# How to check if file was changed since it was last read from? (C#)

Tags: c#, winapi, filesystems

I have a text file that several instances of the same app use to synchronize and exchange data between themselves. In a nutshell it's a plain text file that contains list of data files. These data files come and go on a regular basis.

Is there a reliable way to know that some app wrote to the file since it was last read from? Normally you would use Modified date for it. However the file is accessed so frequently that it will likely be constantly present in memory cache. So there is a flight chance that writing to the file will not alter Modification date.

Is there any other way to know that file was changed.

I know about file system notifications but would rather not use them here.

The software is in C# but obviously I can also use any WinAPI function via InteropServices. Software runs on Windows Server 2008 R2. File system is NTFS. Ideally the method should also work on network shares.

Comment: Should we assume you also don't want to use the FileSystemWatcher class?

Comment: @tvanfosson "I know about file system notifications but would rather not use them here.", or does FileSystemWatcher not use those?

Comment: @Jouke - I wasn't sure if he was against using the FileSysteWatcher class or just the WinAPI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417(VS.85).aspx so I asked.  I can easily imagine not wanting to use pinvoke to get at the WinAPI functions yet not realizing that there is a class that encapsulates the functionality and makes it much easier to use.  If he'd said FileSystemWatcher, I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: I would the FileSystemWatcher as others have mentioned.

Comment: I don't see why the OS caching is going to obscure the modified date - if an app's written to the file and closed it again, the modified date is going to get set, regardless of whether anything's actually been flushed to physical disk or not.

Comment: I appreciate the comments. Perhaps I misstated my question. Obviously I could read and hash the file. And that would provide a definitive answer. However it's unneeded reads of file that I would like to avoid.

Can you please provide more details about the USN journal?

Comment: Although date is stores up to a millisecond, actual resolution of system timer is lower. So it's possible that a process write to a file and then another again (since effectively it's writing to memory) and the timestamp would not change since it happens so fast.

Answer (score 2):

One interesing but (AFAI) barely used feature of ntfs is it's USN Journal, which you can read. It maintaines a list of all changes to the filesystem. The only program I know which explicitly uses it is Everything. But it might be that the FileSystemWatcher is using it internally. Big advantage of reading this log manually is that you can figure out changes that happend while your program was not running.

Answer (score 1):

May be better use sql data base for this. Otherwise you must organize a transaction mechanism for this file.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a hash (MD5 or SHA1 etc) of the file contents to determine if the file has been modified?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you access the file save its Hash (SHA2) and then in the future create a Hash again and compare it to what was saved previously.

Simple and elegant.